# Problem trying to use an item from AjaxControlToolkit in Visual Studio 2008 - asking for ScriptObjectBuilder.cs

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, web, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use the AjaxControlToolkit in Visual Studio 2008.

I download the current binary package 40412 for .NET 3.5 (and have also tried previous binary package 30930 for .NET 3.5).
I extract the contents.
I start a new web site.
I add a new tab and point it at the extracted AjaxControlToolkit dll.
I select an item [Editor] from the list of new Tools and plonk it on a webpage - my bin folder is then updated with a whole host of new dlls.

All looking good so far.

Unfortunately when I click 'start debugging' to test item on the website I am presented with a pop up box titled "Find source" requesting the location of file "ScriptObjectBuilder.cs"

Original location given is i.e. for previous 30930 release -  "C:\Users\swalther\Projects\AspNetAjax\Releases\30930\AjaxControlToolkitSource\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ScriptObjectBuilder.cs"

Note: I googled this problem and another programmer stated that when he got this problem he pointed this "Find Source" dialog at the ScriptObjectBuilder.cs file taken from the corresponding source package and found it still didn't work.

I am on Visual Studio 2008 SP1 as required.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added a ScriptManager control to your page?  You will need one of these for the AjaxControlToolkit controls to work.

Try adding this to your .ASPX page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

You can also achieve this by dragging a ScriptManager control from the Toolbox (under AJAX Extensions I think) onto your page.

Comment: Thanks! I added a ToolkitScriptManager onto the page and it no longer falls over.